# Is SET INTEGRITY of any use after IMPORT statements, or just after LOAD statements?

Tags: db2, import, data-integrity, load

I'm getting the feeling, both from documentation and empirically, that you can only put `SET INTEGRITY` to good use after a `LOAD`, **not** after an `IMPORT`. `LOAD` is mentioned for `SET INTEGRITY`, but not `IMPORT`.

If you try an `IMPORT` with `INSERT_UPDATE`, you may get some rows rejected, as you may with a `LOAD`. Whereas you can embed the use of an exception table directly in the syntax of the `LOAD` or in a `SET INTEGRITY` statement used directly after the `LOAD` statement, and the exception tables will "get" the rejected rows, but hat doesn't appear to be the case with `IMPORT`.

There's no ability to embed the use of the exception table in the `IMPORT` statement, and if you run the `SET INTEGRITY` statement after the `IMPORT` has rejected the rows, it's too late.

Am I right or wrong?

Comment: PS:  you may ask, why not just do a load then instead of an import?  The reason is that you can do an IMPORT which will do either an insert or an update, but you can't do that with a LOAD, you can only do INSERT or REPLACE.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You are right in that you cannot specify an exception table for the `IMPORT` command. Also, there is no need to run the `SET INTEGRITY` statement if you use `IMPORT`.

Here is why:

The biggest reason for `SET INTEGRITY` is based on how `LOAD` and `IMPORT` work. `IMPORT` uses normal `INSERT` statements to get the data into the tables. Doing this engages the database transaction logs, triggers, and referential integrity. If a row is rejected by referential integrity, you will know about it.

`LOAD` bypasses referential integrity, triggers, and database transaction logs, and puts the data directly into the table (though it cannot bypass unique constraints and identity constraints). The main reason why you want an exception table is to catch the data that doesn't load into the table (perhaps it was the wrong data type etc.)

Because you bypass referential integrity, you MUST do a `SET INTEGRITY` afterwards to make the table aware of the data it now contains to see if anything does violate referential integrity (otherwise tables are put into a `CHECK PENDING` state until you do so). (It is also a good idea to run a `RUNSTATS`, `REORG`, `FLUSH PACKAGE CACHE DYNAMIC`, and `REBIND` afterwards too to make sure that indexes and the optimizer know about the new data. Actually, it is a good idea to do that anyway if you do a mass `IMPORT`...but that aside...).

Note that you can use the `MESSAGES` option with both `LOAD` and `IMPORT` to capture errors that happen so you know how to deal with them (usually after the fact though). Note that if you use both `MESSAGES` for a message file and `FOR EXCEPTION <table name>` for an exception table, any rows in error that get put in the exception table don't get listed in the message file.

Here is a good comparison of [LOAD vs IMPORT](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dm.doc/doc/r0004639.html) straight from IBM DB2 documentation (version 9.7)